# What perf_counter really does

Tags: python, python-3.x

Reading the documentation (Python 3.4) about `timeit.default_timer()` it says:

> The default timer, which is always time.perf_counter().

but reading the older documentation (Python 2.7) it says:

> Define a default timer, in a platform-specific manner. On Windows, time.clock() has microsecond granularity, but time.time()‘s granularity is 1/60th of a second. On Unix, time.clock() has 1/100th of a second granularity, and time.time() is much more precise.

So, does `perf_counter()` simply do a choice to keep portability? I mean if the system is windows it returns `time.clock()`, otherwise `time.time()`, so that the precision grades defined above still maintain true, isn't it?

In short, how does `perf_counter()` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere between the Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 `time.perf_counter()` was introduced. Now `timeit.default_timer()` no longer needs to bother with the choice of the best time source, because that's handled in the *time* module now.

In the background `time.perf_counter()` simply calls the best available C API. Details are in [PEP 418](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0418/) including a description of the new Python time API and the native time APIs of the OSes.

Comment: so, does `time.perf_counter()` do what `timeit.default_time()` did before?

Comment: As far as the functionality is concerned: yes. As far as the implementation is concerned: no.